# If SOAP is an XML based protocal used by WebServices why an .asmx service returns JSON?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, asmx

I am confused on one thing. As I have read web services use SOAP protocol for communication and it is an XML based protocol; I was expecting the classical HelloWorld method on an asp.net web service to return an xml based data.

But when I checked with Fiddler i see that the Response Textview has a JSON string instead of an XML structure like:

{"d":"Hello World"}

Does this mean that asp.net web-service implementation returns 'string' types embedded as a value of a property called 'd' ?

Answer (score 2):

Web services don't have to use SOAP as the protocol.  The WCF lets you use all sorts of protocols for your web services.  SOAP and JSON are just 2 of the options.

Answer (score 1):

ASMX services return JSON if you request them via POST, with a content-type containing `application/json`.  More info here: http://encosia.com/2010/03/03/asmx-and-json-common-mistakes-and-misconceptions/

Their return value isn't limited to just strings either.  If you return a collection type, you'll get a JSON array.  If you return a server-side class, that will be serialized into the correct JSON key/value pairs to represent that object.

The `.d` is sort of an orthogonal issue.  It's a security feature to thwart a particular attack against JavaScript's Array constructor.  More here: http://encosia.com/2009/02/10/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have found my answer, here:

"ASP.NET AJAX sends JSON messages to Web Services as opposed to the standard Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP) calls typically associated with Web Services. This results in smaller request and response messages overall. It also allows for more efficient client-side processing of data since the ASP.NET AJAX JavaScript library is optimized to work with JSON objects. "

More details in :
http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-services

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.responseformat.aspx) JSON responses are supported by recent releases of the .NET Framework.